# What is a kafka broker physically?

Tags: apache-kafka

A kafka cluster is composed of multiple brokers. 
Q1. How does a single kafka broker look like physically, is it a machine/pc/node ? 
Q2. If it is a node, then why it is named explicitly as kafka broker as kafka cluster should be enough right? Say a kafka cluster, that's it? 
Q3. Why is there a concept of kafka broker, why don't we have a single kafka cluster and if we want to scale then why not just add more nodes on it or more hardware on that cluster?

Comment: Can you please describe what a node is for you? And what is the difference between a machine and a pc. This terns are quite vage. After all a kafka broker is just a process like a zookeeper (or an apache webserver). You could run a cluster containing of different nodes on a single machine without any kind of virtualisation.

Comment: I was referring to the node as a single machine with the required hardware components for computation. I was referring the machine as a node itself. I was referring the pc as a personal computer, laptop as multiple laptop/pc can also run kafka server which confused me with the fact that if multiple laptop can run the kafka server then wont it is a physical entity which conflicts with the process and this question came which i plotted it down and posted it after doing some research @cricket_007 which I couldn't clarify due to shortage of time and which you downvoted it.

Comment: Kafka IS a process. You can run the [KafkaServer](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaServer.scala#L120-L125) class from IntelliJ... Why is that any different in your mind than any other process? Just because it clusters? I see you have Spark experience... That also runs over many nodes and has clusters.

Comment: And "shortage of time" isn't an excuse, sorry... The documentation is readily available. There are books and youtube videos that very simply explain "[What is Kafka"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiWsPd6JDoo) or [Why it was created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el-SqcZLZlI)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Kafka broker is a logical process, not a phsyical entity. It can be run in a **physical** machine or a virtual machine, or in a container. Though some people, might use the term *broker* and *node* interchangeably. But, as far as the definition goes, a node is a typically a physical entity, a machine or a VM, but a broker is a *process*. We can run multiple brokers in one physical node also.
2. A node represents one entity in a cluster. A Kafka cluster comprises of several Kafka brokers (from 1 to many). If it is a single broker cluster, then we can still call it a Kafka cluster or simply Kafka broker. Though, sometimes when people say a Kafka cluster, they mean every thing that is needed to run Kafka i.e. including the Zookeeper cluster also.
3. Adding more nodes is a way of scaling, but it isn't enough if we just add **physical nodes**, we need to run our Kafka broker processes in it and only then we can distribute the load among Kafka brokers.
   People use only a single Kafka cluster that is comprised of many brokers. Some organizations may also maintain multiple Kafka clusters, most typically for redundancy.

Comment: One additional node to the 3rd point: The idea of having a cluster of different brokers is to have on the one hand replicated data (if one node breaks you dont lose data ... if you have a replication factor bigger than 1) and on the other hand are stilll able to write (produce) data to the cluster.

Comment: 2) "or simply..." I'd rather not conflate that the idea that there is one broker living in a cluster. I'd consider ZK as part of the cluster.

Comment: @cricket_007 , for the replication you mentioned which is helped by multiple broker. If a broker is not a physical entity, say a physical entity 'A' has 4 kafka brokers. How fault tolerance will be achieved if that physical entity itself goes down. And even if that doesn't goes down, how is it possible that one of the broker will go down as it is residing in that physical entity. As long as that physical entity is good, every broker should be good right?

Comment: @potterpod I didn't say that... But if you have 4 copies of anything, and you lose one, then you have 3 copies left. Simple math there, not really sure what isnt clear. As answered as well, brokers are commonly on separate physical machines (think different outlets on the wall). Ideally, every-other broker is in a different "house" (i.e. datacenter). That way, if one "house" is torn down by a tornado, you still have a replica in one (or more) "houses" that are an exact copy of the original house. You can "rebuild the house", then copy data back from one of the other copies.

Comment: @JavaTechnical can we say that "a broker is an instance of kafka running on a node" (where node is a physical server or a VM or a container)

Comment: yes, but *instance of kafka* requires zookeeper also and not just the broker. In future versions, 2.8 (or higher) zookeeper will most liklely be removed, then your statement will be fully true.